# Drag-drop function is not working of Wordpress SweetCaptcha plugin

Tags: wordpress, captcha

I have installed successfully [wordpress sweet captcha](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sweetcaptcha-revolutionary-free-captcha-service/) plugin in my website.

But I found that drag-drop is not working.

Link of website: http://cbtcoaches.vidushiinfotech.info/contact

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: did you check the requirements : Wordpress >= 2.8, cURL extension ? Also your site is using latest jQuery, whereas this plugin is delivered with jQuery-1.4.2

Comment: Yes I have checked everything. But can't find the solution of it.

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html

Answer (score 1):

You simply access your site via ftp and rename temporarely the folder where sweet captcha is.
Then go to your login page and refresh... Try enter now. If you are already in, you just need to go to your ftp login back de folder of the sweet captcha to the original name e update de version of the sweet captcha plugin in your control panel(web).

I did this and worked perfectly.